# Re-render label after save

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Using Visual Studio 2015 CE and LightSwitch HTML Client

I have four properties (Critical, High, Medium, Low) with the data type of Int. I have another property (Risk) with the data type of string that I would like to change the css color based on the four Int property values.

In a ViewDetails screen I have my string property Risk displayed as a label. I need to be able to change the color of the label ex: `.css("color", "red");` when ever one of the four Int properties change and meet a specific condition. Using the `_postRender` function works just fine for setting the initial color but if I open an edit screen and modify the values, Risk doesn't re-render. How can I go about re-rendering Risk? I've tried setting the `dataBind` in the `_postRender` event for each of the four Int properties. The problem I ran into was the `element` parameter provided in the `_postRender` event was not the Risk label. I haven't had much success with anything else tried.

Answer (score 1):

Right, on the add screen I have the below code:

```
/// <reference path="~/GeneratedArtifacts/viewModel.js" />

var cri;
var hig;
var med;
var low;

myapp.AddEditAlarm.created = function (screen) {

    //GET THE VALUES ON THE ADD/EDIT SCREEN CREATION
    cri = screen.Alarm.Critical;
    hig = screen.Alarm.High;
    med = screen.Alarm.Medium;
    low = screen.Alarm.Low;


};
myapp.AddEditAlarm.Save_execute = function (screen) {

    if (screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus == null) {
        //NEW ALARM STATUS
        screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus = 0;
        //WHATEVER YOU WANT TO SET IT AS HERE
    }
    else {
        //HAS IT CHANGED?
        if (screen.Alarm.Critical == cri) {
            //VALUE CHANGED
            screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus = screen.Alarm.Critical;
        }
        else if (screen.Alarm.High == hig) {
            //VALUE CHANGED
            screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus = screen.Alarm.High;
        }
        else if (screen.Alarm.Medium == med) {
            //VALUE CHANGED
            screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus = screen.Alarm.Medium;
        }
        else if (screen.Alarm.Low == low) {
            //VALUE CHANGED
            screen.Alarm.AlarmStatus = screen.Alarm.Low;
        }
    }

    myapp.commitChanges();
};
```

I have declared 4 variables which are accessible on both a custom save button and the created event. on the screen creation, I am setting these 4 variables to the current values of the 4 alarms.

If these change, then the **AlarmStatus** value will change. Currently I have put it within an if, else if statement just for testing purposes. now when you click save, if nothing changes, the colour doesn't change. If any of the 4 alarm values, change then the dataBind will be hit on view screen using the below code:

```
myapp.ViewAlarm.AlarmStatus_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {

        var critical = contentItem.screen.Alarm.Critical;
        var high = contentItem.screen.Alarm.High;
        var medium = contentItem.screen.Alarm.Medium;
        var low = contentItem.screen.Alarm.Low;

        element.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        element.style.fontSize = "18px";

        if (critical == 50 || high == 50 || medium == 50 || low == 50) {
            element.style.background = "RED"; //CRITICAL
            //element.style.opacity = 0.4;
            element.style.color = "white";
            element.innerText = "Critical";
        }
        else if (contentItem.value == 2) {
            element.style.background = "ORANGE"; //HIGH
            //element.style.opacity = 0.4;
            element.style.color = "black";
            element.innerText = "High";
        }
        else if (contentItem.value == 3) {
            element.style.background = "YELLOW"; //MEDIUM
            //element.style.opacity = 0.4;
            element.style.color = "black";
            element.innerText = "Medium";
        }
        else if (contentItem.value == 4) {
            element.style.background = "GREEN"; //LOW
            // element.style.opacity = 0.4;
            element.style.color = "white";
            element.innerText = "Low";
        }
        else {
            //WAIT FOR OPTION
        }
    });
};
```

for now I have set if any of the values equal 50 in the first if statement, then set the alarm status to CRITICAL. I have left the others as 2,3,4 for now. I dont know if you would like a range, or only one of the 4 alarm values is used at the same time, but this method works if any of the values change.

Comment: In your conditions, you have contentItem.value. I need to test the conditions of the four int properties (Critical, High, Medium, Low). Example: If i have Critical with a value of "50",  i need to change the label to one color. If High and Medium are both of a x value, that needs to be another color. How would go about testing those conditions? If the "screen.findContentItem" object was available to me, I would use that but it's not.

Comment: Update - I was going to just delete my comment but I figured this would be helpful for someone else. In order to access other data in the same data set as the contentItem. You can use "contentItem.parent.data.propertyName"

Comment: contentItem.value is referring to the alarm value, so if you have set it as 50, then you would write above (contentItem.value == 50). are these 4 values all referring to one text box, or 4 separate text boxes? and if there are 4 text boxes, one will trigger the fault label? I shall have a play with this tomorrow and get back to you, im based in the UK so you know the GMT

Comment: It's 4 different properties. In my comment with an example, I mentioned the property "Critical" with a value of 50. Critical is one of 4 properties (Critical, High, Medium, Low) which all have their own values. I was able to get all the conditioning working using the method in my comment above. However, after navigating from my save screen back to my main screen. The dataBinding is not firing again. Obviously because the dataBinding is looking for, as illustrated in your example "Enquiry_Alarm" to change. I might need to dataBind all 4 of my properties.

Comment: answer amended from what I know so far, hopefully the core concepts are there and you can adapt your scenario exactly :) if not have you got an example project I can see?

Comment: I appreciate the help! I've got the condition logic working exactly how I want it. My issue now is, changing the Risk label color from a different postRender event. If I understand your code correctly, the binding is on your alarm property and is waiting for a property change event to fire. Since I'm waiting on one of the other properties (Critical, High, Medium, Low) to change, I need to dataBind those properties. The problem I'm running into now is that I don't knw how to access the DOM (label) element from each of the four (Critical, High, Medium, Low) property postRender dataBind methods.